# Linux Mint: Automount package/options how to find on computer and change

Tags: linux-mint, filesystems

When I plug flashdrive it gets automounted. Upon web searching I found only two ways it's done in Linux: `autofs` and using `systemd`.
E.g. rather recent (2017) post: [systemd-automount-vs-autofs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374103/systemd-automount-vs-autofs)

However, I could not find neither `autofs` installed nor file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-scratch.automount` (no files with `auto` in `/etc/systemd`).

`/etc/fstab` also does not have any info on automount, just fixed filesystems.

I want to change options of file system being automounted like in `fstab`. How to find out how automouting is done and change options?

P.S. I'm using Linux Mint now but knowing more general way to do the task is preferred.

Comment: I've always just done it in Disks.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, thank you I can do that after inserting particular USB-stick. My confusion was initially bacause I could not change options for SD-card reader (and still don't know how), but for ordinary USB it works.

Comment: You can't do it for the adapter, you have to do it for the media.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux Mint `udisks2.service` exists is intended for monitoring disks. Also it does automount for new plugged disks. Just disable it:

```
systemctl stop udisks2.service
```

Then you will be mount disks partitions by hand.

Disable autostart (over `systemctl disable udisks2.service`) if you want disable it for further boots.

Comment: Interestingly starting Disks starts `udisks2.service`. Never played with `systemctl disable` before - command wrote nothing, enable command wrote `created symlink`, disabling again wrote `removed symlink` - why different output of `disable` than first time?

Comment: It seems service was not enabled. Is automount capability exists when you disabled (stop before) service?

Comment: Computer did automounting, udisks2 was loaded and active (I did `systemctl -a` before doing actions) and I have not played with it before, After your post I first stopped it then disabled. Now doing in sequence enabling, start, stop and disabling writes `removed sysmlink` on disabling step.

Comment: What type of FS have you mounted? For `fat` FS `codepage=` and `ioscharset=` options exists. For `ntfs` FS only `iocharset=` exists.